# Spring data doesn't add fragment to repository

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

I have a Spring repository that I try to customize. I use fragments because I need a spring bean wired to perform my logic.

Here is the interface I'm using to override the standard logic:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface VerifyingRepo<T, ID> extends CrudRepository<T, ID>, PagingAndSortingRepository<T, ID> {
    @Override
    <S extends T> S save(S s);
}
```

Here is its implementation:

```
public class VerifyingRepoImpl<T, ID> extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements VerifyingRepo<T, ID> {
    private final MyBean myBean;

    public VerifyingRepoImpl(MyBean myBean, JpaEntityInformation<T, ?> entityInformation, EntityManager em) {
        super(entityInformation, em);
        this.myBean= myBean;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {
        myBean.customLogic(entity);
        return super.save(entity);
    }
}
```

Here is my repository I'm trying to use:

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface MyRepo extends VerifyingRepo<MyEntity, Long> {
}
```

I expect my custom logic to fire when I'm invoking the `save()` method of `MyRepo` (when I'm posting a dto to it's representing path). However, Spring instantiates `MyRepo` as `SimpleJpaRepository` and invokes only it's `save()`

Why doesn't Spring add the fragment with my custom `save()` to the resulting repository instance? It doesn't even instantiate my class.

Answer (score 0):

Your interface should be declared as

```java
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface VerifyingRepo<T, ID> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {
    @Override
    <S extends T> S save(S s);
}
```